# How to set values in checkbox using php array and Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I want to set values in checkbox using array and values fetched from database. I have a string like 1,2,3,6,8 which has been converted into string using explode function. I fetched values from database which has 10 elements which has item_id as 1 and so on. Now I want to compare those values to that array one by one and which matches the value, checkbox will be checked and if not checkbox will remain unchecked. Total checkbox are 10. 5 should be selected as per their item_id and array.

```
$string = 1,2,3,6,8;
$array = explode(',', $string);
```

Comment: What are the names of checkboxes?

Comment: put more code // 1 more to go...

Comment: there is no name for checkboxes. if 1=1 then checkbox selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = "1,2,3,6,8";
$values = explode(',', $string);
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{
  if(in_array($i,$values))
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes[]' value='$i' checked='checked'>";
  else
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes[]' value='$i'>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = '1,2,3,6,8';
$array = array_flip(explode(',', $string));

foreach ($checkboxes_from_db as $cb) {
    $checked = isset($array[$cb['item_id']]) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes[]' value='$cb' $checked />";
}
```

Comment: Variable `$checkboxes` comes from?

Comment: He said he has the checkboxes in an array. That's the name I gave it.

Comment: @Fortune that's an invalid edit and I rejected it. Wonder why someone else approved it. That changes the logic.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, i see. But he Barmar already explained it right?

Comment: But he still meant another array, not that one. So his code was fine for that logic and the edit wasn't :)

Comment: I've renamed the variable to be clearer. The question also said that the checkbox value is in the `item_id` field, so I added that.

Comment: Not that any of this really matters. The OP is mainly looking for the logic of adding the `checked` attribute. Notice that he accepted an answer that makes no reference to the checkboxes fetched from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$item_ids = array(1, 5, 3, 10, 11, 23, 6, 9, 2, 8);
$string = '1,2,3,6,8';
$array = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($item_ids as $item_id) {
    $checked = in_array($item_id, $array) ? ' checked' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox"'. $checked . '>';
}
```

[**Demo Link**](https://eval.in/157304)